# What was the largest UTXO ever created in bitcoin’s entire history?

Tags: utxo, history

In transaction ID [8f8210694d3631a88ff410c573d80caf57db1d8af397bd47687aa4e4c1802464](https://blockstream.info/tx/8f8210694d3631a88ff410c573d80caf57db1d8af397bd47687aa4e4c1802464), mined in Block 104770, from early 2011, someone consolidated exactly **400000.00000000 BTC**.

Was this the biggest chunk of ₿ contained in one UTXO in the entire Bitcoin's history?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the largest output ever created was 500,000 BTC:
[29a3efd3ef04f9153d47a990bd7b048a4b2d213daaa5fb8ed670fb85f13bdbcf](https://mempool.space/tx/29a3efd3ef04f9153d47a990bd7b048a4b2d213daaa5fb8ed670fb85f13bdbcf)

I used this Blockchair query to find out: https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/outputs?s=value(desc)#f=index,time,value,recipient,is_spent,transaction_hash

All of the runner-ups seem to be change outputs in the descendants of this transaction.

This transaction is also the transaction with the largest output amount ever, at 550,000 BTC.

Comment: This transaction occurred in mid-November 2011, when the price of a bitcoin was in the range of $2.00-2.50 USD. So interestingly, while this is the largest UTXO in terms of BTC value, it is not even close to the largest UTXO, in terms of (*insert your favourite fiat currency here*) value!